# Please calculate the formula for $\varphi$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Define
$$\varphi:\mathbb{R}^{3}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{3}$$
$$A:((3,1,1),(1,0,0),(5,1,0))$$
$$B:((3,4,5),(4,1,1),(2,0,1))$$

Consider $\varphi$ as linear transformation with matrix

$$M_{A}^{B}(\varphi)=\left[\begin{matrix}1 & 1 & 4\\
2 & 1 & 3\\
0 & 1 & 1
\end{matrix}\right]$$

Please calculate the formula for $\varphi$

Comment: Where are you stuck? What's your definition of $M_A^B(\varphi)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $B=(b_1,b_2,b_3)$ and $A=(a_1,a_2,a_3)$. Since $M_{B}^{A}(\varphi)=\left[\begin{matrix}1 & 1 & 4\\
2 & 1 & 3\\
0 & 1 & 1
\end{matrix}\right]$ we conclude that $$\phi(b_1)=a_1+2a_2\\\phi(b_2)=a_1+a_2+a_3\\ ...$$
So we can calculate $\phi(b_1),\phi(b_2),\phi(b_3)$. Let say that we want to calculate $\phi((x,0,0))$. We write $(x,0,0)$ as linear  combination of $b_1,b_2,b_3$ (i.e $(x,0,0)=\dfrac{x}{15}\left(-b_1+4b_2+b_3\right)$) and then we compute $\phi((x,0,0))$ as
$$\phi((x,0,0))=\phi\left(\dfrac{x}{15}\left(-b_1+4b_2+b_3\right)\right)=\dfrac{x}{15}\left(\phi\left(-b_1\right)+4\phi\left(b_2\right)+\phi\left(b_3\right)\right)=\cdots$$
Do the same for $\phi((0,y,0))$ and $\phi((0,0,z))$ and then 
$$\phi((x,y,z))=\phi((x,0,0))+\phi((0,y,0))+\phi((0,0,z)).$$